# Casting Object to class type

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, casting

This code is from Java SCJP6. It's from the topic of The Comparable Interface from chapter 7 on Collections.
In line 4 we are casting 'Object o' to DVDInfo type. I don't understand this. Why are we casting it as to DVDInfo?

```
class DVDInfo implements Comparable<DVDInfo>{
    public int CompareTo(Object o){
        DVDInfo d = (DVDInfo) o ;
        return title.compareTo(d.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of this implementation of `CompareTo` is to compare by title. Therefore the method needs access to objects of type `DVDInfo`, but the signature of the method only provides `Object o`.
So an explicit cast is needed to covert `o` to `DVDInfo d`.
 If the method is called on an object which is in fact not of type `DVDInfo`, a `ClassCastException` will be trown.

Answer (score 2):

Because without the cast you wouldn't be able to access `DVDInfo` fields/methods.
Like `d.getTitle()` in line 5.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of object and reference. `o` is a reference of the class `Object` and it is an instance of the class `DVDInfo`. Instances are only read at execution time whereas references are read at compilation time. 
If you don't cast `o` to a `DVDInfo`, then, at compilation time `o` is of type `Object`, therefore you can't access its methods, for instance `getTitle()`.